# Methods vs Method assigned to variables in Java

Tags: java, android

I'm sort of confused, I guess this question is just a matter of preference, I just want to understand the difference of the following code.

```
if (IsRegistered() == true) ...

public boolean IsRegistered()
{
 private boolean status = false;
 // blah blah code here
 return status;
}
```

vs

```
isRegistered = IsRegistered();
if (isRegistered)
```

I know both would work, I'm not being pedantic but I just want to understand so I would know my way around.

Comment: The first one is not recommended. It should just be `if (IsRegistered())`. Also, try to follow Java naming conventions: use `mixedCase` for methods/variables and use `CamelCase` for classes/interfaces.

Comment: purely for readability

Comment: BTW, in a method you would not have a variable be stated as private

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (isRegistered() == true) ...
```

This is verbose since you know if it returns true it will do it, if not, it wont. So its the same as doing:

```
if (isRegistered()) ...
```

What it does, its just getting the returning boolean value from the method and checking the condition in the if statement.

Now if you wanted to check the boolean value again, you would need to re-call the method (which may have to do something complex to return that value), BUT if you assign it to a variable first and then check the condition, like this:

```
boolean isRegistered = isRegistered();
if (isRegistered)...
```

Later on the code you can just do it again without calling that method again.

```
if (isRegistered)... // n lines later.
```

hence, avoiding executing the process again.

At the end of the day, it pretty much depends on what you need to do.

Comment: Unboxing the method won't perform more efficient performance on re-calling as Java Interpreter is "clever" and local variables (multiple calls on the same method) lives until the GC harvests garbage. In this case it would be better to use `IsRegistered()` all along.

Comment: `which may have to do something complex to return that value` and `it depends on what you are doing` kinda implies that.

Comment: Nice, seems like the OP never stated enough of what he's trying to do for a helpful solution to be put.

Comment: Yeah, it can vary a lot when they ask a really open question xD.

Comment: @Unihedron - it was really an open question because I don't know what its called, anyway, I just want to clear the cloud in my head regarding which one is better and recommended. Indeed, as I scroll down to read the answers, I realize how open the question was, it lead to many interpretations. But as pointed out "it depends on what you are doing" was sufficient to throw the question out into the rubble. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke a method which has a non-void return type, the method itself resolves to a value the same way that using a variable does. You can either use that value directly or assign it to a variable and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
if ( IsRegistered() )
```

It's the most readable code. Having a variable to "unbox" the method will not do any good; the compiler picks it up and replaces it into the control code itself in an internal optimization pass.

Also, the performance of your `IsRegistered()` method, when the self-optimization of machines is put aside, depends on how your "my code here" works:

```
source : {
   private boolean status = false;
   // blah blah code here
   return status;
}

optimization-passed : {
   return false; // When internal code does not modify "status"

   preturn _status; // When internal code modifies "status"
}
```